# Single Product Identifiers for all the items

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, in-app-purchase

I am in the process of implementing iPhone in app purchases for my application to sell songs.

Songs would be added and delivered from my web server to the iPhone app. I want to allow the user to buy individual songs or subscribe to a particular category like Love, Friendship, etc.
All the individual purchases of songs costs $0.99.

Some links / references state that if I want to sell 100 products/songs means, I have to add 100 entries in iTunes portal.

Here I would like to know one-thing: As I am selling all the individual poems at the same cost, can I create only one in app purchase item/entry and use the same product id for all the songs?

**When a user taps "Buy" for single song in my app, i query the same product id and display like "Do you want to buy this song for $0.99"
and when the user taps "Ok", the payment process gets completed and i call my web service with song-id and deliver the song content for that us**er.

> Will there be any disadvantage / downside in using the same product id
>   for all the songs ( individual songs purchase ) in the iTunes.

I think Non consumable would be relevent for this single song purchase. but i would like to know what would be the correct type to use Consumable / Non consumable?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have different product identifier for each song because each song will represent different feature and to differentiate which song user has purchased you should have some identifier.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use the same product ID for purchases that need to be bought separately.

If you add a non-consumable product that has already been purchased to the payment queue, you will get a pop-up saying that the product has already been bought, and will ask the user whether they want to re-download the product for free. Hence, each non-consumable product can only be bought once.

However, using a consumable product ID can be possible as it can be used in a transaction any number of times, and as long as you handle the maintenance of purchase history yourself, can be used effectively in your situation.